# How can i get the value of id and its index of a newly created record

Tags: php, mysql

When I add a new record, I would like to be able to return its `id` value (the main index, auto int).  Is there a way to do this?

My code:

```
<?

mysql_connect(localhost,"learning_bitcoin","oreo8157");
mysql_select_db("learning_bitcoins") or die( "Unable to select database");
print("open a  database");

$query = "INSERT INTO buy VALUES ('','','".$_GET['market'] ."','".$_GET['price'] ."','','".$_GET['shares'] .
"','".$_GET['real'] ."','')";
$rs=mysql_query($query);

if (!$rs) {
    echo "Could not execute query: $query\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "Query: $query executed\n"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: This is rather vulnerable :-( See about PDO and/or mysqli - AND prepared statements. And now change your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) (soon deprecated, better to use [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)) might be what you are looking for.